# Defining data annotations on a navigational property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have a Person class. A person has a name and a salutation. Salutation is another table in the database (I inherited the database).

In the UI, I want the Salutation to be a required field. Here's what my model looks like:

```
public partial class Person
    {
        public virtual string Id { get; set; }

        public virtual Nullable<long> SalutationId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public virtual Salutation Salutation { get; set; }

        public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Last Name")]
        public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Salutation
    {
        public virtual long Id { get; set; }

        public virtual string SalutationName { get; set; }

        public virtual string Status { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Person> People { get; set; }
    }
```

Is this correct? I am still getting a validation error that says "Salutation is a required field," even when I have entered Salutation.

All this started just an hour ago, until when everything was working fine.

I would've thrashed the issue out myself if I had time to think and wasn't chasing a deadline. Strange what pressure does to your mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short Answer:** Issue is in **the place where you put required validation** for your Salutation.

Your salutation validation attributes should be placed inside the `Salutation model`.

**Edit:** in addition to that your model is using `public virtual` access modifier on each property. I would remove `virtual` if my model don't need that.

Comment: Oh damn! I can't think straight. Thanks. I've been doing all this stuff for years (2 years now). Just that I am in a rush so I can't think at all. Thanks much.

Comment: Good point about removing virtual if I don't need proxies. Performance-wise. Thanks.

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2, no problems

Answer (score 2):

@ElYusubov is correct, but also: `Person.SalutationId` should not be `Nullable`

```
public partial class Person
{
  public virtual long SalutationId { get; set; }
  ...
```

This means every `Person` object must have a valid `SalutationId`, which in turn means a related `Salutation` record in the database.

Comment: Thanks. I agree. Working under a lot of constraints. Can't do anything to the db. The db is not the best. I have presented a very simplified model. I am really working with a horrible db.